# I need a loop to ask user 5 times for a number between 1 and 10

Tags: java

In this function, I need a loop that asks the user for 5 numbers between 1 and 10 and stores the numbers in an array call numArray. I need validation on the user's input. I know I need another loop somewhere that will allow the user to enter 5 different numbers, but I don't know where to put it.

```
public class numberInput {
static int number;

static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // Calls inputNumbers function
    inputNumbers();

}

// inputNumbers function
public static void inputNumbers() {

    System.out.println("Please enter 5 numbers between 1 and 10.");
    number = keyboard.nextInt();

    // If below is true display error message
    while (number <= 0 || number > 10) {

        System.out.println("Error: Enter a number BETWEEN 1 and 10.");
        number = keyboard.nextInt();

    }

}
}
```

Comment: make `inputNumber` prompt for valid input and return it as a value. Loop inputNumbers() 5 times creating and arrey .

Comment: You should make `inputNumbers()` RETURN an `int` instead of using a static variable.

Comment: @Idle_Mind I think he wants 5 numbers... How do you return an ```int```??? QAQ

Comment: I was thinking that `inputNumbers()` method would return just one number by changing `void` to `int`.  Then have the loop up in `main()` and call `inputNumbers()` from within the loop and place the return value into the `numArray`, which would also be located within `main()`.

Comment: @Idle_Mind oh... That works too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like this, ask for 5 distinct numbers:

```
public static void inputNumbers() {
        ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.println("Please enter 5 distinct numbers between 1 and 10.");
            for(int i = 0;i<5;i++) {
                number = keyboard.nextInt();

                // If below is true display error message
                while (number <= 0 || number > 10 || al.contains(number)) {//al.contain(number) means does al have number in it

                    System.out.println("Error: Enter a number BETWEEN 1 and 10.");
                    number = keyboard.nextInt();

                }
                al.add(number);//now add the number into the arraylist
            }
}
```

If you want an array, do:

```
int[] numArray = new int[];
numArray = al.toArray(new int[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you. I was not putting the for loop first and adding the while loop inside it "nesting it". Where you commented that the al.contain(number) just asks if al holds number... thats new to me. Is it asking if a number was already used? For example, if the user enters in 2 twice and if they do it will cause the error message?

Comment: @ZachBeck no, the contain method really meant what it's called(does the array list contain the element), it just returns whether the element you pass in is in the array list.

Comment: It won't throw an error message, it would just return false if the element(```number``` in your case) is not in the array list.

Comment: hmm. Because when I use it an error occurs.  "The method contain(int) is undefined for the type ArrayList<Integer>

        at numberInput.inputNumbers(numberInput.java:30)
        at numberInput.main(numberInput.java:15)"

Comment: @ZachBeck ... Sorry, I spelled contain wrong... It should be ```contains()```

Comment: ah got it. Thank you.